How to solve "RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root!" to use RPi.GPIO on my RPI PI 5 and tensowflow installation problems
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
print("LED on")
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)
print ("LED off")
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

Im̀ trying to proof my rpi pi 5 and i have installed ubuntu 23, and i installed all the necesary lib to use the gpio but the console on the env return
  File "/home/jdam/prueba/prueba.py", line 4, in <module>
    GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

So i don`t understand what is happening,if you could help me that would be wonderful
pd: i am installing tensorflow but i can`t do it because this error:
Building h5py requires pkg-config unless the HDF5 path is explicitly specified using the 

environment variable HDF5_DIR. For more information and details, see https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/build.html#custom-installation
      error: pkg-config probably not installed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


Ask ONE question per post.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can NOT run RPi.GPIO on a Pi5 because the GPIO is on a different chip which is not accessible via memory.
The best option at the moment appears to be Joan's lgpio although you can use libgpiod which is the officially recommended interface (although poorly documented).

I believe gpiozero also works.

@CoderMike gpiozero 2 uses lgpio as its engine, but as the OP was directly coding with RPi.GPIO this didn't seem relevant
